# Xamarin ScrollView not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.winphone

I am reading the [Xamarin Mobile App Development by Apress](http://amzn.to/2b50nGF) and am missing something. I have this code with the unnecessary stuff removed:

```
    public ContentPageExample()
    {
        var layout = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                // bunch of "View"s here
            },
            HeightRequest = 1500
        };

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Content = layout
        };

        this.Content = scrollView;
    }
```

However, the content does not scroll. I tried both in the `WinPhone` and `Android` emulators (don't have a `Mac` handy to try the `iPhone` one). The book says that stuff should scroll. What am I missing?

Comment: It did scroll perfectly fine for me, using `Android` emulator.

Comment: I tried it on Android phone, emulator and also WinPhone emulator it runs properly for me

Answer (score -2):

I would’ve commented, but I do not have the points yet.

I had similar problem: my scrollview worked on mac/iPhone emulator (don’t know about winPhone) but it did not work on Android emulator.

What I noticed is: creating a scroll view in a page works on emulator, putting the page inside a navigationpage and it doesn’t work anymore on emulator... if anyone knows more about this, please tell.

The fix for me was: not using an emulator. Build it to an actual device.

I hope this helps someone, because it took me to long figure out.

Comment: *"i wouldve commentet, but i do not have the points yet"* ... then wait until you have enough rep and I recommend using a spellchecker.

Comment: waiting does not accumulate rep.

Comment: indeed, I guess you can confirm that.